# PHP-FPM - Limit execution time, graceful stop

Tags: php, execution

So I have, in my application, some third-party calls to webservices.

These services can take, on peak times, a lot of time to respond, such that the value I defined for `request_terminate_timeout` on my PHP-FPM setup is reached. Script is then brutally aborted, and I cannot make use of `register_shutdown_function` to attempt a cleanup of the request.

Is there any PHP/PHP-FPM setting I'm not aware of that could limit the **total** execution time of a request? A "graceful" way to handle PHP-FPM termination?

- `max_execution_time` only takes into account time spent in PHP, which in my case is not the cause of long-running scripts
- Using `pcntl` calls, for web requests, doesn't seem such a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

For a long-polling requests I would suggest to use cron/stack approach.

Question, why it was stopped could be addressed to your Apache/nginx server:

```
proxy_connect_timeout 500;
proxy_send_timeout 500;
proxy_read_timeout 500;
```

Also, you could use their triggers to handle timeout errors.

Comment: I don't want to make the requests longer. Issue is that I'm working with somewhat unpredictable services which can sometimes fail to respond with reasonable time spans. Which is why I'm looking for a way to handle failures, at application level, rather than trying to mitigate them.

Comment: In that case I would suggest to use `Flume`. By using it rather simple to track such errors.

Answer (score 0):

try setting the max_execution_time and catch the error

```
<?php
function shutdown()
{
    $a=error_get_last();
    if($a==null) {
        echo "No errors";
    } else {
        gracefully_shutdown();
    }
}
register_shutdown_function('shutdown');
ini_set('max_execution_time', 10 ); //set to 10 seconds

// do some works here
do_some_works();

?>
```

have a look at this link http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php#106061

Comment: Unfortunately, `max_execution_time` is not affected by system calls (such as `sleep`, `curl_exec`, SQL queries, etc.., so it's not enough in my case.